# Batch script copy x lines from a text file without trailing space

Tags: batch-file, copy, lines, spaces

im trying to copy the first x lines
but when i open list1 i see spaces after each line
i'd like to have no space after each lines

```
for /F "eol=; tokens=1 delims=;" %%I in (text.txt) do (
    set /a count+=1
    if !count! leq 10 echo %%I>>list1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
for /F "eol=; tokens=1 delims=; " %%I in (text.txt) do (
  set /a count+=1
  if !count! leq 10 echo %%I>>list1
)
```

Note the space in 'delims=; '.